# How to handle certificates on a Apache reverse-proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, reverse-proxy, outlook-web-app, certificate

Ok, so I was able to assemble an Apache for reverse proxy a bunch of internal sites.

However, those sites use SSL. For the moment, and for testing purposes, I'm using self-signed certificates from the Apache box.

I'm proxying a couple of OWA sites, and 2 https management consoles for a couple of appliances. I'm using name-based vhosts, and it's working fine (using Apache 2.2.14).

However, I want to use the original, correct certificates. I have the original "3rd-party" certificates for all the sites, in .cer and .p7b format, and my question is: can I convert the certificates into something Apache will accept? Or will I need to generate new certificates, from the Apache box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to convert the p7b cert to the PEM format but this can be handled using openssl:

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.p7b -out certificate.pem
```

As for hosting multiple certs on a single Apache reverse proxy using virtual hosts, you will need a little bit more wizardry there. You will need to use [SNI](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI).

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

About SNI, I'm already using it, and it works like a charm :) I'm just testing with some self-signed certificates, and now I want to move to the "real" certificates.

Won't I need the private key for the command you mention to work?

Comment: don't you have the private keys? if you do you can just setup apache to use those private keys. you may need to convert the format.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, I finally got the private keys and everything is up and running! ;) Thanks for your help! :)